# Android Bluetooth Device Picker Usage

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, device, picker

My Application required bluetooth connectivity. And in the first phase I am trying to open up the standard Activity **"Bluetooth Device Picker"** to help user scan for new device or chose a device from the list.

The problem is that I am unable to get any working example for the bluetooth device picker. The task is simple. To start an Activity with Intent *"android.bluetooth.devicepicker.action.LAUNCH"*

And the device picker is opening without any problem.

But the device picker requires four **extras** and I am unable to figure out the exact parameters for two of the extras listed below.

```
.putExtra("android.bluetooth.devicepicker.extra.LAUNCH_PACKAGE","com.extreme.controlcenter"

.putExtra("android.bluetooth.devicepicker.extra.DEVICE_PICKER_LAUNCH_CLASS","com.extreme.controlcenter.WelcomeActivity")
```

What I thought the parameters should be that

*"android.bluetooth.devicepicker.extra.LAUNCH_PACKAGE"*

should have the name of my package, so I passed that only. That is  *"com.extreme.controlcenter"*

The second should be the name of the component that must receive the broadcast that is done after a device is selected. Here I tried putting the name of the class that has the *onReceive()* function.

But the problem is that the onReceive() function is NOT getting called when a device is picked in device picker!

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            String action = intent.getAction();

            //Device Selected on Device Picker
            if("android.bluetooth.devicepicker.action.DEVICE_SELECTED".equals(action)) {
                //context.unregisterReceiver(this);

                BluetoothDevice device = (BluetoothDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                Toast.makeText(context, "device" + device.getAddress(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                String MAC = device.getAddress();
                //Log.d("my", MAC);

                Intent intent2 = new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, ControlActivity.class);
                intent2.putExtra(EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS, MAC);
                startActivity(intent2);
            }


        };
```

I have created an **Intent filter** and registered a receive in the onCreate() of the main Activity

```
 // Register the BroadcastReceiver
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.bluetooth.devicepicker.action.DEVICE_SELECTED");


    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

One thing is that if I don't provide those two extras, the **Broadcast** event is received successfully. But that code only runs on my TAB, but same is crashing in cell phone. So I think providing those two extras are mandatory.

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 1):

"com.extreme.controlcenter.WelcomeActivity" in your EXTRAs needs to be a BroadcastReceiver class such as MyBroadcastReceiver.class.getName(). I also have it declared in the manifest inside the  tags

Answer (score 0):

Tested on android 12, pure kotlin code, no manifiest configuration needed.

```
private const val ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SELECTED =
    "android.bluetooth.devicepicker.action.DEVICE_SELECTED"

fun showBluetoothSearch(activity: Activity) {
    activity.registerReceiver(bluetoothReceiver, IntentFilter(ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SELECTED))
    val bluetoothPicker = Intent("android.bluetooth.devicepicker.action.LAUNCH")
    activity.startActivity(bluetoothPicker)
}

private var bluetoothReceiver: BroadcastReceiver = broadcastReceiver { _, intent ->
    if (ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SELECTED == intent.action) {
        val device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE) as BluetoothDevice?
        toast(device?.address)
    }
}
```

It's strange that there is no official document for the system device picker use case, I combined the code from several sources. Hope it helpful.